# How to bypass a variable in a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = str(number)
    def x(self, string):
        self.number = str(random.randint(0,10))
        string = self.name + string + self.number
        return string
        
my = Hello('hello', 2)
r = my.x("world")
print(r)
```

Example output:
helloworld8

Is there any way to bypass this `self.number = str(random.randint(0,10))` to prevent randomising the number?. Sometimes I just want the number that I send here `my = Hello('hello', 2)` ie. 2

Comment: You can make the `number` parameter optional. Use `number=None` instead of just `number` in the `__init__` line, and then check whether `number in None`. If so, randomize, otherwise use the number given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (as described in my comment) would be the introduction of a default value for the `number` parameter:

```
import random

class Hello:
    def __init__(self, name, number=None):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number if number is not None else random.randint(0, 10)

    def x(self, string):
        string = f'{self.name} {string} {self.number}'
        return string
        
my = Hello('hello', 2)
r = my.x("world")
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a default value - `None` to `number` parameter.

So when you pass in a value to `number` in your object initialization, only that value will be printed.

When there is no value passed to `number`, a random value will be generated and printed.

```
import random
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, name, number=None):
        self.name = name
        if number is not None:
            self.number = str(number)
        else:
            self.number = number

    def x(self, string):
        if self.number is None:
            self.number = str(random.randint(0,10))
        string = self.name + string + self.number
        return string
```